# Reading recent entry from a file based on a key

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut

Input file, fruits.txt:

```
JAN,APPLE 
FEB,MANGO 
JAN,ORANGE 
MAR,APPLE 
FEB,APPLE
```

Expected output file:

```
MAR,APPLE
FEB,APPLE
JAN,ORANGE
```

For getting the above output, below code is used:

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -A m_arr

cat fruits.txt > /tmp/ID.part

while read line
do
Month=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1)
Fruits=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2)
m_arr[${Month}]=${Fruits}
done < /tmp/ID.part

for i in ${!m_arr[@]}
do
echo "$i,${m_arr[$i]}"
done
```

This works fine for small number of data in input file. I have 200 000 entries and observed that cut command is very slow. Tried with awk as well, did not get a better result. My requirement is to read the file from row1, with the key as column1. I need to updated entry for each key.

Comment: `My requirement is to read the file from row1, with the key as column1` -- Can you explain more on this? It is not quite clear

Comment: 1. Why are you copying `fruits.txt` to `ID.part`? Do you assume that `fruits.txt` can be modified by some third party during your script execution? 
2. You tagged it `bash` but start your script as `/bin/sh`. Is using bash-only commands accepted by you?

Comment: From a file with million entries, I want to latest one. First column would be the key, which would be repeated in the file. Data in second column is what I am looking for. I need to the most recent value for a given key. Most recent value is stored at the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be done pretty easily with `Awk`, you just need to hash the values of `$1` in `$2` once you delimit the file with a `,` separator

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{key[$1]=$2; next}END{for (i in key) print i,key[i]}' file
```

Also if you want to speed up things while processing a million line file, you can change the localization settings to speed up the execution while parsing, you can pass `LC_ALL=C` locally to the command. See [Stéphane Chazelas's answer on what "LC_ALL=C" does?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/112235)

Comment: Yep, this is certainly more performant than my bash-only solution. On a 1-million line test file (repeating `fruits.txt` in the question) awk returned in about 1 second, whereas bash took around 28 seconds. I note that this returns output in the order in which keys were first seen, rather than last seen (as in the example output.) Not sure if this matters. One question though - why include `; next` ? I don't see a performance increase from this.

Comment: @ghoti : Yes it is kind of a habitual one. It makes sense for multiple action blocks but probably not needed here.

Answer (score 3):

In bash version 4, you can declare an associative array and populate it with the result of `read`, splitting your lines with a custom `IFS`:

```
$ declare -A a
$ while IFS=, read key value; do a["$key"]="$value"; done < fruits.txt
$ declare -p a
declare -A a=([MAR]="APPLE" [FEB]="APPLE" [JAN]="ORANGE" )
```

If you want to generate that specific output from the array, you'll also require a loop:

```
$ for key in "${!a[@]}"; do printf '%s,%s\n' "$key" "${a[$key]}"; done
MAR,APPLE
FEB,APPLE
JAN,ORANGE
```

Comment: Nice! but it's just that OP had said a large file, so refrained from posting this approach

Comment: @Inian - your approach also stores results in associative array, so the impact of the input set being large should be about the same. Does awk handles this data structure more efficiently in memory? Or are you thinking about the speed?

Comment: Speed mostly! 've seen over the past, the script approach slows down as the file size increases, but never had seen it firsthand

Comment: Exactly, I see the script slowing down as the file size increases. So looking for some better way to handle it.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti, this solution worked at took 2 minutes for a large file. However solution shared by Inian took only a second for the same file.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest one using GNU **`datamash`**:

```
datamash -st, -g1 last 2 <file
```

- `g1` - group by the 1st column
- `last 2` - keep the last value of the group

---

The output:

```
FEB,APPLE
JAN,ORANGE 
MAR,APPLE
```